# ¿Por qué me da error de salida de rango este sencillo programa?

Tags: c++

Se supone que vas introduciendo números, los va almacenando y si el último número que introduces es el mejor de todos o el mayor de todos, te lo indica.
La idea es ordenar los elementos del vector conforme los introduces y hacer la comprobación.

Me da un error en tiempo de ejecución, concretamente cuando introduzco el primer número. El error es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código este:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;


void keep_window_open() { cin.ignore(); cin.get(); };

int main()
{
    double x{ 0 }, min{ 0 }, max{ 0 };
    vector<double> tuggo = { 0 };

    cout << "Enter doubles:\n";
    cout << "Enter a | to terminate program instead.\n";

    while (cin >> x)
    {
        if ((char)x == '|')
        {
            break;
        }
        tuggo.push_back(x);

        min = tuggo[0];
        max = tuggo[tuggo.size()];

        short(tuggo);

        if (x < min)
        {
            cout << x << "The smaller so far.\n";
        }
        else if (x > max)
        {
            cout << x << "The largest so far.\n";
        }
        else
            cout << x << "\n";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

C++ indexa desde 0, no desde 1. Esta es la instrucción que sale de rango:

```
max = tuggo[tuggo.size()];
```

Debería ser:

```
max = tuggo[tuggo.size() - 1];
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Cero (`0`) no es el mejor valor para almacenar en `min` y `max`, ya que te puede fallar con determinadas entradas de datos. Deberías almacenar respectivamente el mayor número disponible y el menor número posible:

```
double min{ std::numeric_limits<double>::max() },
       max{ std::numeric_limits<double>::min() };
```

De esta manera, por pequeño que sea el primer valor, siempre será menor que `min` y por grande que sea el primer valor siempre será mayor que `max`.

---

El nombre `x` no es nada explicativo, no deja clara la intencionalidad de la variable, cambia a algo más claro como (por ejemplo) `dato_entrada`.

---

Capturar un `double` y comprobar si su valor equivale a un entero es una idea terriblemente mala. Si te introducen el valor `124.8` el programa finalizará ya que al convertir `124.8` a `char` se volverá `124` que es `|`.

---

La línea `short(tuggo);` ni siquiera compila... pero aunque compilase no tiene sentido alguno.

---

Este código no te va a capturar el menor y mayor valor del `std::vector`:

```
    min = tuggo[0];
    max = tuggo[tuggo.size() - 1];
```

Te captura el primer y último valor, que a no ser que introduzcas los números en orden no cumplirá con tus expectativas. Cambia el código por:

```
    min = std::min(min, dato_entrada);
    max = std::max(max, dato_entrada);
```

Comment: Ahh... tipico. Muchas gracias. Sabia que era algo en esas instrucciones.

Comment: Si inicializa `min` en 0 no se yo qué mínimos espera conseguir...